Testing to find polarity of PCB power connector
I've got a PCB I ordered from China. It required a 5V input voltage through a barrel jack. The issue is there is no sign showing the polarity (positive or negative center) so I don't want to connect the power in case it fries the board. I have done this before.
I have a multimeter and i did a Ohm resistance test that shows the following results. However I'm not sure if it indicates positive or negative center. What is the correct polarity for the input voltage given the resistance test results (below)? Thanks.
The barrel jack of my DC input adapter has a mark that indicates Positive center polarity:

Connecting to the multimeter as shown gives a reading of 1.61 Ohms on the resistance test:
 
Connecting to the multimeter as shown gives a reading of -1.219 Ohms on the resistance test:
 

The first thing here is to explicitly state that you should have bought things from someone who has the documentation to safely operate it. If they don't, they probably have no idea what they're selling, and you risk buying something dysfunctional. Here it's extremely easy to figure: the connector will match the polarity of the electrolytics on the board.

Anyway, this is really a usage question, and you asking it the way you do, missing a factor of 1 Million, and what this device is really doesn't allow me to conclude there's any electrical engineering to be done here. VTC.

That would exclude a huge amount of items on ebay that are made in china and sold with no instructions. That doesn't make them dysfunctional, in this case I managed to get the PCB working fine.

I think it should exclude all these things, indeed! No documentation means no functional guarantees. "it does what it does as long as it does it, we tell you nothing binding about what it's supposed to do" is not a basis for helping anyone use a device.

again, I think of it this way: this is a platform for helping people with engineering. Usage information that they should have gotten from the vendor of their devices has exactly zero future value for other readers, and only means we're doing free work for someone having no cost for their own sales documentation. That is doubly bad, because it means we're subsidizing bad business practices.

On the big electrolytic capacitors, there should be some indication of polarity (often only - is marked).
Put your multi-meter in continuity mode, and check if the pads  from the capacitor show continuity to the barrel connector : if so, then the - of the capacitor is the - of the supply, and the + of the capacitor is the + of the supply.
If you get both continuities, the risk of mistake is very small.
If only the - match, then the risk is a bit more significant.
If you get no continuity at all (or only the +), then you need another way to find out

That's what I was going to post - except to use resistance mode, not continuity mode. The latter will beep for low resistance, such as briefly when the DMM's inadvertently charging a board capacitor. Resistance mode keeps it clear. (I almost never use continuity mode for that reason, and because the beeping can annoy people around :-) )

Thanks . I did this and using a guide to barrel connectors I was able to identify the connection from the barrel to the -ve side of the cap and then work out the location of the -ve terminal and I am pleased to say I got the device working fine :)

The M in front of Ω means million. So you read very high resistance values here and they will not tell you anything useful.
A negative resistance value should tell you, that this measurement method cannot be used at all in this context.
There is a good chance, that the negative supply pin has a direct connection to the USB connector shields. At least it looks like that on the pictures.

Thanks, I am sure this is the case. Useful to know about the 'M' mark.
